How to narrow return type of generic function?
Given a general RPC 2.0 request schema defined as
import { z } from "zod";

const rpcRequestMessageSchema = z.object({
  jsonrpc: z.literal("2.0"),
  method: z.string(),
  params: z
    .union([z.array(z.unknown()), z.object({}).passthrough()])
    .optional(),
  id: z.union([z.string(), z.number(), z.null()]).optional(),
});

and specific RPC requests' params and result schemas defined as
const m1name = "m1" as const;
const m1paramsschema = z.object({ m1foo: z.string() });
const m1resultschema = z.object({ m1bar: z.string() });

const m2name = "m2" as const;
const m2paramsschema = z.object({ m2foo: z.string() });
const m2resultschema = z.object({ m2bar: z.string() });

const allMethods = {
  [m1name]: { params: m1paramsschema, result: m1resultschema },
  [m2name]: { params: m2paramsschema, result: m2resultschema },
};

how to construct a makeMethodRpcSchema() helper that looks something like the following,
function makeMethodRpcSchema<Method extends keyof typeof allMethods>(
  method: Method
) {
  return rpcRequestMessageSchema.extend({
    method: z.literal(method),
    params: allMethods[method].params,
  });
}

but that correctly narrows down the type of the return value when called with a specific value?
Currently, when calling makeMethodRpcSchema("m1"), the type of the returned value includes fields from "m2". How to type this function in such a way that it narrows down the type to include only "m1" fields when called with "m1"?
For example, when constructing the object below, intellisense will suggest both m1foo and m2foo as params even though the schema is built for "m1",
const rpcm1Schema = makeMethodRpcSchema("m1");
type RpcM1 = z.infer<typeof rpcm1Schema>;
const obj: RpcM1  = {
  params: {
    // Here both "m1foo" and "m2foo" are suggested
    // but only "m1foo" would be valid with this schema.
  }
}


Blecch, those zod types are so huge that I can barely get IntelliSense to print them out fully.  Since I have no idea what's going on, the best I can write is this version.  Obviously there's some generic relationship between K and the type that comes out of rpcRequestMessageSchema.extend, but I don't know enough about zod to see it. Could you [edit] the code to show the exact types you expect to see for the results of makeMethodRpcSchema("m1") and makeMethodRpcSchema("m2")?

Thanks @jcalz, agree, the types are huge. Unfortunately I don't know how to construct the type that would result in the behavior I'm looking for. Thanks for giving it a go!
